# Invalid Token error when generating email confirmation or password reset tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Situation: 2 public facing web servers in a server farm are connected to a common database. Another 3rd web server for administration and content management is located within enterprise private network connected to public database side. E.g. all 3 web servers are communicating with the same database server - same user database.

All 3 web servers, same OS, same...  All 3 have the same Machine Key.

Generating a token from either `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync` or `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` *from the admin site* results in an **invalid token** error when used by `ConfirmEmailAsync` or `ResetPasswordAsync` *on the public web servers*.

In short, Admin site requires the ability to resend email verifications and password resets.

Thoughts? Ideas?